# How to set relative layout x, y and height constraint for image as platform dependent in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am struggle to set image relative layout parameters like height, width,x and y constraint is set as per platforms. I am very new to this layout. Please suggest any idea how to get this.

Answer (score 0):

x and y attributes arent available for RelativeLayout, the only one that supports it is AbsoluteLayout that is deprecated for a while and also is discouraged for usage cause can't addapt for multi-screens.

Answer (score 0):

Found a sample https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17742/relativelayout-in-xaml you set it relatively to other views as the documentation states